# Firefox not printing image files

Tags: firefox, printing

When printing from Firefox to my HP OfficeJet Pro 8100, standalone image files don't print. I can print a web page as a whole(images included), but if I right-click on an image and select "View Image", then try to print that, it gets stuck in my print queue and never prints. I get the same result if I save the image to my desktop and open with Firefox.

If I open the same image file in IE, or another photo viewer it will print without issue.

I only have one physical printer, but Firefox will print an image to the "Microsoft Print to PDF", and "Microsoft XPS Document Writer."

Any ideas?

Additional Details:
Windows 10 Home
Firefox 62.0b12
Using the latest HP drivers downloaded from their website
Happens with both PNG and JPEG files

The problem has persisted for several updates of both Firefox and Windows

Fitting sample page:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-printing-problems-firefox
The page itself prints fine, including all of the images.

This image is from that page:
https://prod-cdn.sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2018-02-16-07-19-41-1caeb6.png
If I print the image directly from that link, or save it to my desktop and print, it hangs in my printer queue.

**New Information**
I found a really old Brother Laser printer in the garage and hooked it up. That's working as expected, so I guess that's pointing more to the HP drivers. Still, Firefox seems to be the only program that's having any problems.

Comment: What version Firefox and OS? And can you add an example url/image for reference (something generic)?

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7 and HP8610. I had a similar problem a couple of years ago, but that was a fonts issue (web fonts on some pages caused the printer to hang, and I had to turn off Options --> Fonts & Colors --> Advanced --> Allow pages to ...). Not sure how that would affect an image though. Also I presume you have the same problem with jpg images? In any case, some conversion from image to postscript or whatever the HP printers use these days is messing up.

Comment: Yes, JPG as well. I have updated the post